# How To Customize Image/Logo In Google Knowledge Graph

Tags: seo, google, knowledge-graph

I'm noticing a pattern regarding Google's Knowledge Graph (KG) and I wonder if others are experiencing the same.

I want to add a custom text-based image to show up in the Knowledge Graph. Google provides the [markup](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo) for logos in the knowledge graph, but when I add it to the Head section, then Fetch as Google using GWT, the logo still does not show.

The image that does show on the KG is from our Google Business Page (GBP). The image is an exterior view of our office, showing our door. If I remove this image from our GBP, refreshing the Search results yields another photo from our GBP. I tried uploading the Intended photo to our GBP, but still does not show. Interestingly, if I remove ALL of our photos except the Intended photo from GBP, refreshing the Search results displays a placeholder image, not my Intended one! Why is that?!

Question: Does Google only show specific types of images on their Knowledge Graph, ie logos or stock photos, but not text-based images? They are pretty clear about the ability to customize the schema markup, using any image URL you specify. Why won't it show my Intended photo?

Thanks!

Comment: It takes quite a bit of time before anything shows up in the knowledge graph. Do not think the two are linked. They are not. While the query engine will query the knowledge graph, the knowledge graph is a fact link database and not a search database. It takes time after a page is indexed for anything of value to the knowledge graph to show up. You will have to do your work then be patient. As well, Fetch as Google is not immediate. The regular googlebot will show up 1-2 days later and make the request official. Until then, anything you see is temporary. Cheers!!

Comment: As well, please also know that the knowledge graph will take from the Google+ account since the account is fully vetted and the data can be directly fed to the knowledge graph in a trusted manner. One other source of trusted data that can be directly fed to the knowledge graph is Wikipedia. It is likely that the G+ account will be taken over any mark-up on the site or even Wikipedia. The only way to know for sure that G+ is taken first is to experiment. I am just saying, do not be surprised.

Comment: My experience differs a bit in that after Fetching as Google, the new/updated landing page does indeed show up only a few minutes later, not 1-2 days later.

Comment: Sometimes it does. However, the full effect does not happen until the regular googlebot shows up. I have seen the SERP snippet change, however, proper indexing no longer occurs from what I can see until the regular googlebot arrives soon after. For some, the SERP snippet changes for a period then reverts back while for some it does not change until the regular googlebot arrives. I am not sure where the line is drawn for this. Clearly, G likes you! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The master plan by Google is that Showing the most relevant images from your Business as per UX point of view towards the User. Now they want 360 degree view of your business culture & existence that's why in the panel there is Images Section **Eg: Logo, Interior, Exterior, Team etc.**  Now you could change it with login via Google+ or directly login into your **Google My Business Listing Page.**
In case of preferable images you could Refer - [Suggest a change to a Knowledge.](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6325583?hl=en)