# How many Days does Google Take to Reflect the Knowledge Graph and Site Navigation Element?

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

I wanted to see my website something like "the next web" shows up on the SERP page. So I have submitted the structure data to my website (I hope I did right). I am really not sure how many days does google take to reflect the changes. Can anybody help me in that?

**Reference Image:**

[image]

Comment: There's no guarantee your site will get sitelinks. It may never happen.

Comment: And there is a long list of factors before getting a knowledge graph card. I suggest searching this site. We have addressed this in different was before.

Comment: Days, weeks, months, maybe never!

Comment: See also: [How To Customize Image/Logo In Google Knowledge Graph](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102020/how-to-customize-image-logo-in-google-knowledge-graph) and [What markup should be used so that Google generates a knowledge graph for our organization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106692/what-markup-should-be-used-so-that-google-generates-a-knowledge-graph-for-our-or)